# hover elements on the chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a bar chart. I'd like to do the same option, but instead of highlighting, it should draw the line. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Definitely possile. You might want to draw divs on mouseover that overlay the drawn bars. You could set the height the same, then use an offset equal to the barwidth / 2. On mouseoff you'd set the opacity of the div to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option I can think of is to just `append` a `<line>` to the SVG whenever you `mouseover` a bar, and remove that line when you `mouseout`. It's similar to the solution proposed by @ckersch, except that it has more overhead (you're changing the DOM every `mouseover`/`mouseout`), but is easier to implement and doesn't change the structure of your SVG at all. You can add the following when you append the bars:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d){
    svg.append("line")
       .attr("class", "mouseover-line")
       .attr("x1", x(d[0]) + x.rangeBand()/2)
       .attr("x2", x(d[0]) + x.rangeBand()/2)
       .attr("y1", y(0))
       .attr("y2", y(d[1]));
       .style("stroke", "#000")
})
.on("mouseout", function(){
    d3.selectAll(".mouseover-line").remove();
});
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/bm7qcLrg/).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with a combination of css and javascript. You can define css for a class as follows:

```
.hiddenLine{ opacity: 0; }
```

If you build your dom with both bars and lines as children of `g` elements, with bars first so the lines render on top of them, like so:

```
...
<g class="bar">
  <rect></rect>
  <line></line>
</g>
//more bars
...
```

The following javascript will create the hover affect:

```
d3.select('.bars')
  .on('mouseover', function(d){
    d3.select(this).select('line').classed('hiddenLine', false);
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d){
    d3.select(this).select('line').classed('hiddenLine', true);
  });
```